# How to exploit Lottery Game?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, buffer-overflow

After exploiting this code and finding out if you enter 16 different digits
[Output using exploit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0rtv.png)
I am trying to understand why this is the case. Is it because of the memory location?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int entry[6];
  int results[6];
  int i = 0, tmp = 0;

  /* Generate power balls */                                                                   
  srand(time(NULL));                                                                         
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {                                                       
    results[i] = rand() % 99;                                                           
  }


  printf("RULE: You are to enter a sequence of six two-digit numbers between 10 and 99. \n");
  printf("  - The numbers should be separated by a single space. \n");
  printf("  - The seventh number should be -1, indicating the completion of the sequence \n");
  printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
  while(tmp != -1) {
    scanf("%d", &tmp);
    if (tmp == -1) break;
    entry[i] = tmp;
    i++; 
  }

  /* Check results */
  int match = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf("The lottery number is: %d\n", results[i]);
    printf("Your guess is: %d\n", entry[i]);
    if (results[i] == entry[i]) {
      match++;
    }
  }

  if (match != 6){
    printf("Unfortunately, there has been a mismatch! Better luck next time!\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("Congratulations, all the numbers match! You have won a gazillion dollars \n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I tried finding the memory location of each array: [Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXLMl.png) / [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fner3.png)

But I don't understand how they are related or even if they are part of the exploit.

Comment: Presumably `entry` array is under the `results` array so check that in gdb. By writing past the end of `entry` you are overwriting `results` so they will match. My guess is you do not even need the last `18` (which probably causes your stack smashing error).

Comment: @Jester, are you saying that since I am overwriting the entry by entering more the requested number of entries, the addresses will match with the addresses of results?

Comment: Yes that is what is likely happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, where `sizeof (int)` is 4, these arrays align 32 bytes apart

```
(gdb) print &entry
$1 = (int (*)[6]) 0x7fffffffe7b0
(gdb) print &results
$2 = (int (*)[6]) 0x7fffffffe7d0
```

with `results` being placed after `entry`, and have 8 bytes of padding between them.

```
     |entry                  |padding|results                |stack
     | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | P | P | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ? | ? | ? |
i   =  0   1 ...               6   7   8   9 ...      12  13  14  15  16
tmp = 10  12 ...          16  17  18  10  12 ...          16  17  18  -1
```

Until `tmp` is `-1`, `i` will continue to increment, writing the value of `tmp` into `entry[i]`. This eventually overflows `entry`, and starts writing to the padding bytes, and then the `results` array.

On my machine, `i`, `tmp`, and `match` are placed *before* the arrays, and what follows the arrays are likely [canaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries), that trip the stack protection when their values are changed.

Entering only 14 values, instead of 16, and then `-1`, causes the `results` array to be overwritten exactly, without tripping any stack protection.

This does all fall under the purview of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), though.

Comment: Yes, `gcc -fstack-protector-strong` (which is on by default in some distros) places arrays at the top of stack frames, so scalar locals can't be overwritten by buffer overflows.  That's why this exercise has 2 arrays.  And yes, GCC will align-by-16 for arrays of 16 bytes or larger, including locals.   (Surprisingly, the x86-64 System V ABI even specifies that as part of the ABI, not just for static storage.)

Comment: Also yes, this is attacking the asm implementation of the program logic that one compiler on one machine happened to create with certain compiler options, not the C abstract-machine logic.  A different compiler might have laid out the arrays with `entry` at the higher address, right below a stack canary, making this attack not possible.  (And other attacks, like overwriting a return address above the canary, also not possible unless you can get it to leak some memory contents including a random canary value.)  So yeah, the question should have included those details, like disassembly!